# Plotting Vectors 2D (Two-Dimensional): How to plot a vector field in Spherical Coordinates in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

How to plot a vector field in Spherical Coordinates in Python
like this equation:

[image]

Is it possible to plot a graph (2D or 3D) of vector field [image]
in spherical coordinates using matplotlib?

Need some help.

Answer (score 2):

You may change parameters in the following script to explore vector field

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
pts = 100
x_range = 10
y_range = 10
colors_in_quiver = 20
headwidth=5.0
minlength=3
pivot='tail'

# Initialization
x,y = np.linspace(-x_range,x_range,pts), np.linspace(-y_range,y_range, pts)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
theta = np.arctan(y/x)

# Components of H
r_comp = 2*np.cos(theta)/r**3
theta_comp = np.sin(theta)/r**3

# Plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,9))
ax.quiver(x, y, r_comp, theta_comp,
          [pd.qcut(r_comp.flatten(), q=colors_in_quiver, labels=False)],
          headwidth=headwidth,
          minlength=minlength,
          pivot=pivot, 
          cmap='hsv')
```

[image: plot of vector field]

---EDIT----

Assumption: since there is no `z` component. I assume it is free to move. Hence, in the code below, both `z` and `phi` moves freely.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
pts = 20
x_range = 6
y_range = 8
z_range = 4

def comps(levels):
  # Initialization
  x,y,z = np.linspace(-x_range,x_range,pts), np.linspace(-y_range,y_range, pts), np.linspace(-z_range,z_range, 5)[levels]
  x,y,z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
  r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
  theta = np.arctan((y+1e-10)/(x+1e-10))
  phi = np.arccos((z+1e-10)/(r+1e-10))

  # Components of H
  r_comp = 2*np.cos(theta)/r**3
  theta_comp = np.sin(theta)/r**3
  phi_comp = phi
  return x,y,z,r_comp, theta_comp, phi_comp

# Plot 
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)).add_subplot(projection='3d')
for i in range(4):
  x,y,z,r_comp, theta_comp, phi_comp = comps(i)
  ax.quiver(x, y,z, r_comp, theta_comp,phi_comp,
            color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'][i],cmap='hsv')
```

[image]

As you can see above, it looks like there are layers stacked in the pile. This shape is determined by the third component. Since, it is missing in this case, I have sampled it in layered style. You will get differently shaped 3D plots dependent upon the third component (which you are free to change).

NOTE: Consider the case of gravitational field, it has only one component `G(x, y ,z) = -g*e_z` . So, if you plot a 3D graph without any assumption then, you will get a cuboid with all parallel vectors pointing downwards. However, since we know that earth is sphere, we are no longer free to choose `x,y,z` and so if we include the information of the manifold(not in physics/math language but plain language) in the code to plot `G(x, y ,z)`, we would get a sphere with vectors on it surface pointing towards it's center.

Comment: It’s help to me @Lawhatre, but your codes is based on (radial, azimuthal, polar). If it is (radial, polar, azimuthal), is it different? But for sure, if it can be plotted in 3D, it will be able to see a clearer picture. So what do I have to do in order to make a 3D plot?

Comment: The field provided in question ```H(r, theta)``` has only two axis i.e ```e_r``` and ```e_theta```. So, we can only plot 2D graphs. 3D isn't possibe for this case.

Comment: @TubeTT, please post a new question with ```H``` having three components ```H(r, theta, phi)```. Afterwards, you can add comment here to provide link to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the convention in which the symbols theta and phi are reversed (both in meaning and in order listed) is also frequently used, especially in physics. This is especially confusing since the identical notation (r,theta,phi) typically means (radial, azimuthal, polar) to a mathematician but (radial, polar, azimuthal) to a physicist [ref](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/creating_and_grading_assignments.html)

Comment: Consider the gravitational field strength, g, near to the surface of the Earth, the field lines look like:  G(x, y ,z) = -g*e_z (a uniform vector field), It has the same direction and magnitude everywhere.

Comment: I don't know if I'm wrong or not. If wrong, please advise.

Comment: pls post this  on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ . As far as coding part is concerned, this is pretty much it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691625/326758

Comment: I was not sure about the physics/math of the question. Hence, I asked you to put question on different platform regarding the phy/math of it (not code). Anyway, I'm updating my answer with some assumption. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you [posted this on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691625/123208), I *assume* your equation is using the physics convention for [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), with theta=0 at the north pole.

You can easily [plot 3D vector fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/plot_field3d.html) using [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), which is a huge mathematics / algebra system built on top of Python. If you can write Python, it's easy to start working with SageMath. You don't even need to install it: you can run Sage scripts in your Web browser, on the [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) server.

Sage has [sophisticated support for vector fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/vector_calculus/vector_calc_curvilinear.html), with a variety of coordinate systems built-in. It *can* do [Cartesian plots working in spherical coordinates](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/manifolds/sage/manifolds/differentiable/vectorfield.html#sage.manifolds.differentiable.vectorfield.VectorField.plot), but it's allegedly rather slow, and I haven't experimented with it.

The code below creates an interactive 3D plot of your vector field, doing the coordinate transformations explicitly. Sage lets us define symbolic variables, which can be used to create equations and do algebra and calculus. Sage syntax is *almost* identical to plain Python, although as a mathematical convenience it permits the use of `^` as well as `**` for exponentiation (Sage uses `^^` for exclusive-or).

The Sage `plot_vector_field3d` function works with Cartesian coordinates. It expects its function argument to be a list, tuple, or vector of functions that each take x, y, z args. So we need to transform those args to polar form, call the `H` function with the polar args, then transform the polar value returned by `H` to Cartesian. By working with symbolic variables and functions, we can transform the `H` function itself, as this code illustrates.

```
# Create some symbolic variables
x, y, z = var('x,y,z')
rad, th, phi = var('rad,th,ph')

# Transform polar coords to Cartesian
def sphere_xyz(R, theta, phi):
    r = R * sin(theta)
    return r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi), R * cos(theta)

# Transform Cartesian coords to polar
def xyz_sphere(X, Y, Z):
    r2 = X^2 + Y^2
    r = sqrt(r2)
    R = sqrt(r2 + Z^2)
    return R, atan2(r, Z), atan2(Y, X)

# The equation in polar coords
H_polar(rad, th, ph) = (2 * cos(th) / rad^3, sin(th) / rad^3, 0)

# Transform equation to Cartesian
R, theta, phi = xyz_sphere(x, y, z)
H_xyz(x, y, z) = sphere_xyz(*H_polar(rad=R, th=theta, ph=phi))
print(H_xyz)

lo, hi = 3, 6
P = plot_vector_field3d(H_xyz,
  (x, lo, hi), (y, lo, hi), (z, lo, hi),
  colors='rainbow', plot_points=[6, 6, 6])

perspective = False
projection = "perspective" if perspective else "orthographic"
P.show(frame=True, projection=projection)
```

The script prints this for the transformed version of the `H` equation.

```
(x, y, z) |--> (2*z*sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, 0, 2*z*cos(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2)
```

Here's a screenshot of the plot, using an orthographic projection.

[image: 3D vector field]
It's a lot easier to see the structure in the [interactive 3D view](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkk1vm0AQhu_8ipFz8OKs2opIOVTiFKnqMbJycFLVaA1D2QgzZHbtGP_6zoKNIRaymI9932dnuIMnRuMRHO3lr9vvqLY5HA1bs6vRRScNnYYzpCGnlifd6fMyjtgUGnyloa3stRZykmorqUd38MKmcSXxHlqqDUNOxIUDT_Bk2KOzpokKLMG1FTJmp-6s1kETvell458RyI9Ffg0rcLZRfTEe0ugP3Eh1JcJOhX7dR6FviNaX2uXUDGlEmGD1mD2SsGQDltpoeNXwdoVJhGazTeAeXrfJyOc-2CtOBrL1LSFtb9tkBixXNN40ieKgeg3EYjMQVgj4cTDeUgO2mY0u-p31oZoMPxYzlYwXjeE7SHX7oC_zmiR-fBnBaDPbyGwFIj4ZxeVTiIUjLOsahuveVriaQKa9WDrqpWEvcdSybbzqRQSpJg29kyA-Rs_y0tbksyPmnjgrLdbFQzF0axlksB2OyPBUNw3Ot0Aac6qJXSpfpW129LnUg25LYu7SP4_iJs9fIWiRXSt29oji_svUDoWR3kNKxpPCYtKxAFvC9ARKOyyIfUX_2MgN80X0_M1V9KlKNntMX_iAYj4KprfX-D_2Txig&lang=sage).

You can drag the view with the mouse & zoom with the mouse scroll wheel, the shift & ctrl keys can also be used. On touchscreens, use one finger to rotate, two fingers to pan & zoom.

Comment: If the Sage window is too narrow on your device, you can expand it with this bookmark: `javascript:(function(){let%20w=prompt('Width?','130%');if(w)jQuery('.sagecell').css('width',w);})()`

Comment: You may enjoy this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57679/38535 which uses Sage to calculate Lagrange points & plot them on the pseudo-potential surface of the rotating coordinate system (it's a pseudo-potential because it combines gravitation with centrifugal force).